# How to get all of the deactivated Features in the farm that could be activated for the specific web using Sharepoint Server Object Model?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-object-model

I need to get list of SPFeatureDefinitions like in ManageFeatures.aspx page. Probably it should be smth like this:

```
...
using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
foreach (var spfeature in SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions)
{
    result.Add(spfeature);                           
}
```

But how can I be sure that `spfeature` could be activated on `web`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using  if (spfeature.Scope = SPFeatureScope.Web)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I have to get all feature definitions and then filter them by web scope. Here is the code:

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteId))
{
    using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb(selectedWeb.Id))
    {
        foreach (var spfeature in SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions)
        {
            if (spfeature.Scope.Equals(SPFeatureScope.Web) && !spfeature.Hidden)
            {
                var feature = new Feature();
                feature.Name = spfeature.DisplayName;
                feature.Id = spfeature.Id;
                feature.IsActive = web.Features[spfeature.Id] != null;

                result.Add(feature);
            }                            
        }
    }
}
```